# Sending Refreshed Excel Sheet Every Workday using VBA Excel/Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Every day at 3PM I have to send out an Excel Workbook to a colleague. The macro in the workbook simply copies all cells in one sheet and Paste Special to another sheet and saves the workbook. I have written the macro to do this and also to send it to an email address, however I struggle to have it sent automatically. I have instructed Scheduling Tasks already, but I don't know how to make the link between opening Excel, performing the Marco, saving the workbook and sending it to a specified person. Code is below - thanks for you help.

```
Sub Fixing()

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
      xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("I7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = "my email address"
        .Subject = "Daily Email"
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ("F:\Excel Models\Daily Email.xlsm")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: To run this as a scheduled event, you might be better off converting it to a VBScript or PowerShell script. Either could create an `Excel.Application` object the same way you are creating an `Outlook.Application` object and use it to peal off the worksheet, save it and continue on with your mailout routine.

Comment: by `Scheduling tasks` you mean **Windows Task Scheduler**?

Comment: Thanks for posting this question.  I am looking forward to using something just like this.

Answer (score 1):

Create `VBScript file` e.g. `start excel action.vbs` with the following code inside:

```
    dim EXL
    set EXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'not required
    EXL.Visible = true

    'your file and macro    
    EXL.Workbooks.Open "full path to your excel file including extension here" 
    EXL.Run "Fixing"

    'close everything
    EXL.Quit
    Set EXL = Nothing
```

Save the file and set `Windows Task Scheduler` to to run that `vbs` file at 3 PM.

Comment: Thank you both for this question and answer.  You just gave me a visual representation for what I knew I'd be wanting to do soon, but didn't have the code in my mind's eye.